# quoting HTML attribute values

Tags: html, xhtml, sgml

I know [the spec allows both](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#attributes) ' and " as delimiters for attribute values, and I also know it's a good practice to [always quote](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html).

However I consider " being the cleaner way, maybe it's just me having grown up with C and C++' syntax.

What is the cleanest way of quoting attribute values and why? Please no subjective answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are fine, but **Double quotes** are better (IMHO) as you reduce the risk of dynamic values causing errors. e.g.

```
<input value='${lastName}'/>

<input value='O'Graddy'/>
                ^^^^^^^
```

vs.

```
<input value="${lastName}"/>

<input value="O'Graddy"/>
```

Comment: True, though you should really be escaping everything instead of hoping for the best.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a lot of rules to remember if you want to omit quotes around attribute values. It’s probably easiest to just use quotes consistently; it avoids all kinds of problems.

If you’re interested, I did some research on unquoted attribute values in HTML, CSS and JavaScript a while ago, and wrote about it here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

I’ve also created a tool that will tell you if a value you enter is a valid unquoted attribute value or not: http://mothereffingunquotedattributes.com/#foo%7Cbar

Answer (score 0):

Either is good, as long as you use it. `"` is more popular.