# Uncaught Syntax error on onClick function javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to output some strings in the onclick anchor function.I have used proper escaping but anyhow its returning error.

My code is:

```
$output .= '<a title="Minus this" href="#" onclick = removefromCart("' . $item . '", "' . $nonce . '", ' . $deductQty . ');></a>';
```

And also used this :

```
$output .= '<a title="Minus this" href="#" onclick = "removefromCart("' . $item . '", "' . $nonce . '", ' . $deductQty . ')"></a>';
```

But in both cases there is **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**

Comment: On javascript you cancat with + not .

Comment: You are doing the quotes wrong.

Comment: Can you kindly check my answer again? I had updated immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes is totally wrong. Do this way, using the first one:

```
$output .= '<a title="Minus this" href="#" onclick=\'removefromCart("' . $item . '", "' . $nonce . '", ' . $deductQty . ');\'></a>';
```

See the `'`s I have added and removed spaces? And please, next time, don't mingle both PHP and JavaScript. It's confusingly dangerous.

See also:

- [Are single quotes allowed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354)
- [Is there a better way to write this php code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735058)

Comment: Not works! `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'removefromCart' `

Comment: @desiDesign My mistake. Updated. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quotations to represent string in HTML element

```
$output .= '<a title="Minus this" href="#" onclick = "removefromCart(\'' . $item . '\', \'' . $nonce . '\', ' . $deductQty . ')"></a>';
```

Comment: Even single quotes are allowed in HTML. `:)` Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

For greater than or equal to PHP5

```
$output .= '<a title="Minus this" href="#" onclick = removefromCart($item,$nonce,$deductQty);></a>';
```

For Less than PHP5 try it

```
$output .= '<a title="Minus this" href="#" onclick = removefromCart(' . $item . ',' . $nonce . ', ' . $deductQty . ');></a>';
```

Comment: 2nd one comes like this in inspect : `onclick="removefromCart(9452902fb2661d341204550e807a1442,6c9864b056,"`